# How can I create a column and row dynamic filter for my advanced filter macro?

Tags: vba, excel

I am creating this mini "search engine" that would allow me to filter websites by their categories, to see if they match a specific category and so on. I have created a macro for the advanced filter and to past my information in another sheet and another one to clean my selection.

The problem is that I can't seem to make it dynamic in the way that I need (current region won't work because I might have to jump columns or rows). I will attach my VBA code below (with my attempt to make it dynamic).

```
    Sheet6.Range("B1").CurrentRegion.AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, _
    CriteriaRange:=Sheet1.("A1:A01").End(xlDown), CopyToRange:=Sheet5.Range("D10:AR10"), Unique:= _ False (I tried to insert my VBA as code - I hope it works).
```

So basically, I need my filter to capture any text or number within my workbook. The filter header is from A1:AO1 and it's located on sheet1, the data is stored in sheet6 and the data should be retrieved in sheet5.

Comment: If you are trying to find results in dynamic columns you should not use filters.  Filters are only for when you know the column you want to search in.  You could just use "Find" on the range (the whole sheet) and have find return the address (row & column).  From there you can move that data and any other associated data anywhere you want.

Comment: Please post some screenshots to show what you have and what you want to achieve. Also please describe what is your exact problem with your code.